# Can't scrape contributors div from github insights page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I am trying to scrape github contributor insights using NodeJS, puppeteer, and cheerio.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'https://github.com/grey-software/grey.software/graphs/contributors';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.waitForSelector('#contributors', {
    visible: true,
  })

  await page.goto(url);
  const pageContent = await page.content()

  const $ = cheerio.load(pageContent);
  $('.contrib-person').each(function (i, elem) {
    console.log(elem)
  });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I get the following error when I run the code above

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for selector "#contributors" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

The #contributors div should load within the 30 seconds, but I always get this timeout.
Note: page.waitForNavigation() gives the same timeout error

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is you are waiting for the selector to exist... Before you go to the website in the first place. use `page.waitForSelector()` after you use `page.goto()`

Comment: I've actually tried implementing that method yet the contribution section doesn't seem to be rendering. While I don't get the rejection warning above, the scraper can't detect elements with class .contrib-person since the component isn't rendered. Hence the for loop doens't execute and there is no output.

Comment: add visible to true then as the second parameter

Comment: Second parameter for waitForSelector() is already visible: true. Is that what you're referring to ?

Comment: oh wait yes nvm. You could do page.goto(url, {waitUntil:"domcontentloaded"}) https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagegotourl-options